# could not free the root in avltree

Tags: c, pointers, tree, free

I am a new learner to C, and could not understand clearly about pointer or some other things, so I am trying to implementing an AVLTree in C, but I have got error in my code. Some of the problems might be foolish, but I really confused on such things. For this one, I want to free node in an AVL tree. But I am having so much difficulty with the pointer and free and sth else.I hope that you would be patient with my fault.

Here is my AVL tree structure:

```
    typedef struct AVLTreeNode {
    int key; 
    int value;  
    int height; 
    struct AVLTreeNode *parent; 
    struct AVLTreeNode *left; 
    struct AVLTreeNode *right; 
} AVLTreeNode;

typedef struct AVLTree{
    int  size;      // count of items in avl tree
    AVLTreeNode *root; // root
} AVLTree;

AVLTreeNode *newAVLTreeNode(int k, int v )
{
    AVLTreeNode *new;
    new = malloc(sizeof(AVLTreeNode));
    assert(new != NULL);
    new->key = k;
    new->value = v;
    new->height = 0; // height of this new node is set to 0
    new->left = NULL; // this node has no child
    new->right = NULL;
    new->parent = NULL; // no parent
    return new;
}

AVLTree *newAVLTree()
{
    AVLTree *T;
    T = malloc(sizeof (AVLTree));
    assert (T != NULL);
    T->size = 0;
    T->root = NULL;
    return T;
}
```

and my free function is :

```
void destroy_avltree(AVLTreeNode *N)
 {
    if (N->left!=NULL) destroy_avltree(N->left);
    if (N->right!=NULL) destroy_avltree(N->right);
    if (N->parent && N->key < N->parent->key) N->parent->left = NULL;
    if (N->parent && N->key > N->parent->key) N->parent->right = NULL;
    free(N);
 }

// put your time complexity analysis for freeAVLTree() here
void FreeAVLTree(AVLTree *T)
{
    assert(T!=NULL);
    destroy_avltree(T->root);
    free(T);
}
```

I could free any other node but the root.
here is my result might looks like:

preorder tree:
(7, 7) (3, 3) (1, 1) (0, 0) (2, 2) (5, 5) (4, 4) (6, 6) (11, 11) (9, 9) (8, 8) (10, 10) (13, 13) (12, 12) (14, 14)

after free:
(39674416, 0)

It seems remain the pointer of sth.But I could not figure out what's going wrong.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What does `T->root` point to after you call `FreeAVLTree`?  And should it point there?

Comment: Thank you for reply!I thought T->root is freed.cuz if I add" free(T->root) "just after the line "destroy_avltree(T->root)" it shows "double free or corruption"

Comment: Freeing a pointer releases the memory back to the system - it does not set the pointer to NULL.

Comment: thanks a lot !!! Suddenly the light shoots me:) I could not figure it out without your help.

Comment: @AShelly I have another question about pointer in this programme.Is it convenient to bother you for some help?

Comment: just for others come to this question:    I added T->root = NULL;
    free(T->root); after destroy_avltree(T->root); and it works:)

Comment: You should replace `new` with another name.

Comment: @Michi sorry?what do you mean?could you explain it more clearly?

Comment: @fender Of course I can, but please [read this first](https://stackoverflow.com8u/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new) and [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_and_delete_(C%2B%2B))

Comment: sure,thanks for recommandation.I am not good at basic theory,I will read this